# Getting names of GAC Assemblies

Tags: c#, gac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List all DLL's implementing a specific interface from the GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747991/list-all-dlls-implementing-a-specific-interface-from-the-gac)

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the Fully Qualified Names of all the .DLL's registered in the GAC? Basically, I would like to emulate the functionality of Visual Studio when you right click on References and then go to "Add a Reference"....How it populates the ListBox with all the Assemblies.

Comment: @dash -- This question is about finding DLLs that implement an interface. It has no code example of loading DLLs from the GAC.

Comment: From the accepted answer - "Here's a .NET wrapper around fusion.dll that allows you to enumerate all the assemblies in the GAC." which points to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8285/GAC-API-Interface - hopefully that's what you want.